# Пропадание фрагментов при повороте экрана?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, customview

Для каждого FrameLayout создаётся фрагмент, внутри Activity в методе onCreate() (каждый раз)

Управление размерами некоторых элементов идёт в CompositeLayout . При повороте экрана пропадают фрагменты не все (каждый раз разное количество) и иногда размеры элементов внутри фрагмента неправильного размера. В случае если используется только один фрагмент ( windows = 1  смотри CompositeLayout.java ) то всё работает корректно. Параметр windows  принимает значения от 1 до 4-х.

Есть какие нибудь идеи где может быть проблема?

CompositeLayout.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import model.Settings;


public class CompositeLayout extends LinearLayout {
static final String INSTANCE_STATE = "instanceState";
static final String ORIENTATION_STATE = "orientationState";

int Orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL;
int windows;
LinearLayout WindowFrame[];

public CompositeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CompositeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public CompositeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

void init(){
    WindowFrame = new LinearLayout[4];
    windows = getWindowFromPreferences();
}

int getWindowFromPreferences(){
    int window;
    try {
        SharedPreferences Preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        window = Integer.valueOf(Preferences.getString(Settings.WINDOWS, Settings.DEFAULT_WINDOWS));
    }catch(NumberFormatException|NullPointerException e){window = Settings.TWO_WINDOWS;}
    return window;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    WindowFrame[0] = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.window_1);
    WindowFrame[1] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.window_2);
    WindowFrame[2] = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.window_3);
    WindowFrame[3] = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.window_4);
    /*for(int i = 0; i < windows; i++){
        WindowFrame[i].requestLayout();
    }*/
    setOrientation(Orientation);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    MeasureFrames(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}


void setCompositeOrientation(int orientation){
    if(orientation != getOrientation()){
        Orientation = orientation;
        setOrientation(orientation);
        requestLayout();
    }
}

void MeasureFrames(int width, int height){
    int WidthPart = (width / windows);
    int HeightPart = (height / windows);

    for(int i=0;i < WindowFrame.length;i++) {
        if (i < windows) {
            WindowFrame[i].setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams WindowParams = WindowFrame[i].getLayoutParams();
            if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL) {
                //VERTICAL orientation
                WindowParams.height = HeightPart;
                WindowParams.width = width;
              } else {
                //HORIZONTAL orientation
                WindowParams.height = height;
                WindowParams.width = WidthPart;
            }
            WindowFrame[i].setLayoutParams(WindowParams);
        } else {
            WindowFrame[i].setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }
        WindowFrame[i].requestLayout();

    }
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putInt(ORIENTATION_STATE,Orientation);
    return bundle;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if(state instanceof Bundle){
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        Orientation = bundle.getInt(ORIENTATION_STATE);
        state = bundle.getParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE);
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
}
```

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.android.nik.timeline.ViewLargeScreenActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.android.nik.timeline.CompositeLayout
    android:id = "@+id/windows_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:maxWindows="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.android.nik.timeline.CompositeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось всё просто, требовалось переопределить методы measureChild и measureChildWithMargins в CompositeLayout.java . Тогда фрагменты не пропадают.